# Two python loops that look like they should do the same thing, but output different results?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tfidfvectorizer

I was trying to complete Udacity's Lesson 11, on vectorisation of text, yesterday. I went through the code and it all appeared to work fine - I take some emails, open them up, remove some signature words and return the stemmed words of each email into a list.

Here's loop 1:

```
for name, from_person in [("sara", from_sara), ("chris", from_chris)]:
    for path in from_person:
        ### only look at first 200 emails when developing
        ### once everything is working, remove this line to run over full dataset
#        temp_counter += 1
    if temp_counter < 200:
        path = os.path.join('/xxx', path[:-1])
        email = open(path, "r")

        ### use parseOutText to extract the text from the opened email

        email_stemmed = parseOutText(email)

        ### use str.replace() to remove any instances of the words
        ### ["sara", "shackleton", "chris", "germani"]

        email_stemmed.replace("sara","")
        email_stemmed.replace("shackleton","")
        email_stemmed.replace("chris","")
        email_stemmed.replace("germani","")

    ### append the text to word_data

    word_data.append(email_stemmed.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

    ### append a 0 to from_data if email is from Sara, and 1 if email is from Chris
        if from_person == "sara":
            from_data.append(0)
        elif from_person == "chris":
            from_data.append(1)

    email.close()
```

Here's loop 2:

```
for name, from_person in [("sara", from_sara), ("chris", from_chris)]:
    for path in from_person:
        ### only look at first 200 emails when developing
        ### once everything is working, remove this line to run over full dataset
#        temp_counter += 1
        if temp_counter < 200:
            path = os.path.join('/xxx', path[:-1])
            email = open(path, "r")

            ### use parseOutText to extract the text from the opened email
            stemmed_email = parseOutText(email)

            ### use str.replace() to remove any instances of the words
            ### ["sara", "shackleton", "chris", "germani"]
            signature_words = ["sara", "shackleton", "chris", "germani"]
            for each_word in signature_words:
                stemmed_email = stemmed_email.replace(each_word, '')         #careful here, dont use another variable, I did and broke my head to solve it

            ### append the text to word_data
            word_data.append(stemmed_email)

            ### append a 0 to from_data if email is from Sara, and 1 if email is from Chris
            if name == "sara":
                from_data.append(0)
            else: # its chris
                from_data.append(1)


            email.close()
```

The next part of the code works as intended:

```
print("emails processed")
from_sara.close()
from_chris.close()

pickle.dump( word_data, open("/xxx/your_word_data.pkl", "wb") )
pickle.dump( from_data, open("xxx/your_email_authors.pkl", "wb") )


print("Answer to Lesson 11 quiz 19: ")
print(word_data[152])


### in Part 4, do TfIdf vectorization here

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import stop_words
print("SKLearn has this many Stop Words: ")
print(len(stop_words.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english", lowercase=True)
vectorizer.fit_transform(word_data)

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

print('Number of different words: ')
print(len(feature_names))
```

But when I calculate the total number of words with loop 1, I get the wrong result. When I do it with loop 2, I get the correct result.

I've been looking at this code for far too long and I can't spot the difference - what did I do wrong in loop 1?

For the record, the wrong answer I kept getting was 38825. The correct answer should be 38757.

Many thanks for your help, kind stranger!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines don't do anything:

```
email_stemmed.replace("sara","")
email_stemmed.replace("shackleton","")
email_stemmed.replace("chris","")
email_stemmed.replace("germani","")
```

`replace` returns a new string and doesn't modify `email_stemmed`. Instead you should be setting the return value to `email_stemmed`:

```
email_stemmed = email_stemmed.replace("sara", "")
```

So on and so forth.

Loop two does actually set the return value in the for loop:

```
for each_word in signature_words:
    stemmed_email = stemmed_email.replace(each_word, '')
```

The code snippets from above are not equivalent in that at the end of the first snippet `email_stemmed` is entirely unchanged due to `replace` being used in correctly, while in the end of the second one `stemmed_email` has actually been stripped of each word.

Comment: Amazing, that was ridiculously quick. Thank you so much, you've saved me my sanity. I'll mark this as complete when I can - there's a 10 minute window.

Comment: Haha happy to help :)

Comment: While I'm here, why does that cause so many new words at the end? I guess they just appear multiple times from my source data and therefore appear in the list?

Comment: Do you mean why does loop one have more words than loop two? My assumption would be that the words replaced in loop two aren't replaced in loop one due so they show up at the end.